# De onde vem a expressão «lacrou»?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, origem

De um tempo pra cá ouço jovens usando a expressão "lacrou/lacrador" (pelo menos no Brasil) quando alguém manda bem em alguma coisa.

> [**lacrou**](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/lacrou/)
>   Maneira de dizer que a pessoa foi bem em algo. 
>   Realizou algo e obteve sucesso.

Veja alguns exemplos:

> *Lacrou* na cara das inimigas!
> Você é um *lacrador* mesmo.

De onde surgiu essa expressão?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Encontrei o artigo, [*“Lacrou”: qual é a origem desse termo?* de Pedro Katchborian (UOL, 15-4-2014)](http://youpix.virgula.uol.com.br/memepedia/lacrou-o-cu-origem/), que ao que consegui apurar dá a resposta correta.

***Lacrar***, neste sentido, parece ter tido a sua apresentação pública a 27 de Novembro de 2013, [neste vídeo cómico de Romagaga Guidini no YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NDABMdXQySw). Transcrevo um bocadinho (ênfase minha):

> Olha meu amor, a Britney, querida, sambou! Sambou, humilhou a cara das inimigas, querida, com o álbum Britney Jean, tá querida? Fechou, querida. A Britney **lacrou**, querida. Sabe o que é **‘lacrou’**? **Lacrou**, querida. Fechou, humilhou as gerações, querida, para essas veadas, que tava [não compreendi], n’ é querida? que a Britney não canta, querida. Meu amor, acorda, querida. Porque a Briteny é a Britney, querida. A Britney fecha. A Britney humilha, A Briney **lacra, querida, o cu das inimigas**, tá querida? A Britney **lacra**, querida; humilha gerações, meu amor. Lacra.

Com data anterior encontrei o verbo *lacrar* apenas no sentido convencional de ‘selar com lacre, fechar’ [(Dicio)](https://www.dicio.com.br/lacrou/). A partir dessa data encontra-se frequentemente o verbo *lacrar* no sentido de ‘arrasar a competição, o público’. A ideia por detrás no novo sentido parece ser que o desempenho foi tão bom que encerra, sela, qualquer discussão sobre o assunto.

O efeito do vídeo da Romagaga transparece no [Google Trends](https://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=lacrou), que mostra uma aumento do uso de *lacrou* na net precisamente a partir da semana de 27 de Novembro de 2013 (no site é possível ver a data de qualquer ponto do gráfico):
[image]
Frequência de *lacrou* na net [(Google Trends)](https://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=lacrou)